# nested foreach loops in R to update common array

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I am trying to use a couple of foreach loops in R to fill out a common array in parallel. A very simplified version of what I am trying to do is:

```
library(foreach)
set.seed(123)
x <- matrix(NA, nrow = 8, ncol = 2)

foreach(i=1:8) %dopar% {
    foreach(j=1:2) %do% {

      l <- runif(1, i, 100)
      x[i,j] <- i + j + l     #This is much more complicated in my real code.   

    }
}
```

I would like to code to update the matrix `x` in parallel and have the output look like:

```
> x
       [,1]      [,2]
 [1,]  31.47017  82.04221
 [2,]  45.07974  92.53571
 [3,]  98.22533  12.41898
 [4,]  59.69813  95.67223
 [5,]  63.38633  55.37840
 [6,] 102.94233  56.61341
 [7,]  78.01407  69.25491
 [8,]  26.46907 100.78390
```

However, I cannot seem to figure out how to get the array to be updated. I have tried putting the `x <-` elsewhere, but it doesn't seem to like it. I think this will be a very easy thing to fix, but all my searching has not lead me there yet. Thanks.

Comment: hi there, just a general tip:  if using a specific package, it is helpful to indicate this in the sample code. (I've edited your code to reflect)

Comment: Thanks @RicardoSaporta I forgot to do that when making the example small

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`foreach` loops are used for their return value, like `lapply`.  In this way they are very different from `for` loops which are used for their side effects.  By using the appropriate `.combine` functions, the inner `foreach` loop can return vectors which are combined row-wise into a matrix by the outer `foreach` loop:

```
x <- foreach(i=1:8, .combine='rbind') %dopar% {
   foreach(j=1:2, .combine='c') %do% {
     l <- runif(1, i, 100)
     i + j + l  
   }
}
```

You can also use the nesting operator: `%:%`:

```
x <- foreach(i=1:8, .combine='rbind') %:%
   foreach(j=1:2, .combine='c') %dopar% {
     l <- runif(1, i, 100)
     i + j + l  
   }
```

Note that `set.seed` probably won't do what you want, since it is being performed on the local machine, while the random numbers are generated in different R sessions, possibly on different machines.

Comment: did not realize this about `set.seed` -- thanks for pointing that out

Comment: It reports `Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "%do%""` for the first code block

Answer (score 5):

Just to add something to Steve's answer: I think the crucial point is that the parallel backend starts multiple Rscript.exe processes (as can be seen in the task manager).
Certain objects that are used within `foreach`, i.e. in your case `x`, are then *copied* into the memory that was allocated for each of these processes. I am not sure how the copying is handled in the `foreach` package, but with the `*ply` functions of the `plyr` package you have to explicitly state the objects that should be copied.
The different processes do not share their memory. (I am not aware of other R packages that can use shared memory...)

One can demonstrate that the matrix `x` is actually copied by using `.Internal(inspect(x))` to print object `x`'s memory location.

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

x <- matrix(1:16, nrow = 8, ncol = 2)
#print memory location of x
capture.output(.Internal(inspect(x)))[1]

#create parallel backend; in our case two Rscript.exe processes
workers=makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(workers)

y<- foreach(i=1:8, .combine='rbind') %dopar% {
    #return memory location of x
    capture.output(.Internal(inspect(x)))[1]
}

#print matrix y
#there should be two different memory locations - 
#according to the two Rscript.exe processes started above
y

#close parallel backend
stopCluster(workers)
```

The matrix `y` reads

```
       [,1]                                                                          
result.1 "@0x0000000003dab910 13 INTSXP g0c5 [NAM(1),ATT] (len=16, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5,..."
result.2 "@0x0000000003dab9b0 13 INTSXP g0c5 [NAM(1),ATT] (len=16, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5,..."
result.3 "@0x0000000003dab910 13 INTSXP g0c5 [NAM(2),ATT] (len=16, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5,..."
result.4 "@0x0000000003dab910 13 INTSXP g0c5 [NAM(2),ATT] (len=16, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5,..."
...
```

You should find two different memory addresses there.